# Box rotation parallel to selected face

Tags: three.js

On Sphere face click add Box parallel to the face.
To get (x, y, z) rotation angles, I'm using this method:

```
function getRotation(faceNormal){
    var planeVector1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0);
    var matrix1 = new THREE.Matrix4();
    var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors(planeVector1, faceNormal);
    var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationFromQuaternion(quaternion);
    var a = new THREE.Euler( );
    a.setFromRotationMatrix ( matrix, 'XYZ' )
    return a.toVector3();
}
```

Result looks like this, boxes are parallel to the face but have different orientation:
[image]

I want boxes to have same orientation and be parallel to the face as in image below, how can I achieve this:

[image]

Created fiddle example, just click on sphere to add box: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c12vdwbx/2/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c12vdwbx/3/ or use `square.lookAt( camera.position );` or use sprite.

Comment: How simple with sphere, thanks @WestLangley:) But if I change sphere geometry to cylinder geometry, its not working. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c12vdwbx/6/). Should I count perpendicular position to the face instead of mesh.position?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c12vdwbx/8/ -- I do not know what you want to do, otherwise I would provide an answer...

Comment: @WestLangley last fiddle is what I needed, you can move it to answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object3D.lookAt()` is a handy method that will serve your purposes.

First create your mesh's geometry so it is "looking" by default in the direction of the positive-z axis. Then call `mesh.lookAt()`. For example:

```
square.lookAt( intersects[ 0 ].face.normal );
square.position.copy(intersects[ 0 ].point );
```

Note that in this case, we call `lookAt()` first, and translate the object second.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c12vdwbx/8/

three.js r.73